# ls discrepancy - found vs not found (No such file or directory) - on the same file

Tags: bash, bash-expansion

Wildcarding one part of the file name, ls says it exists:

```
$ ls *rammar*  
London_Grammar_-_Hey_Now_Official_Video-nMEHJPuggHQ.mp4  
London_Grammar_-_Hey_Now_Radio_1_s_Big_Weekend_2014-on1QEcz1sTI.webm  
London_Grammar_-_Interlude_Live_on_KEXP-7eNA90LlxmY.mp4
```

Wildcarding another part of the file name, ls says it does not exist:

```
$ ls *7eNA9*
ls: cannot access `*7eNA9*`: No such file or directory
```

ls is not aliased

Return code (via `echo $?`):

```
2
```

man ls:

```
Exit status:  
 2      if serious trouble (e.g., cannot access command-line argument).
```

CentOS

```
7.5.1804
```

bash

```
4.2.46(2)
```

coreutils

```
GNU v8.22
```

Comment: Works for me GNU 8.28 version of `ls`

Comment: @Jesse_b my GNU coreutils version is 8.22

Comment: Also works for me in centos 7 with v8.22 ls.  Are you sure you are in the right directory when executing that one?

Comment: Looks like you have a subdir 'London_Grammar' or somesuch, and it's thereby showing entire contents of that dir.

Comment: @Jesse_b I had tried to use the markup to highlight the searched for terms: **rammar** and **7eNA9** -- otherwise, as far as I can see, all chars match my term display - mostly copy pasta

Comment: I think @steve's theory is correct.  Can you execute simply `ls` on the directory and show the output?  Or what about `ls */*7eNA9*`?

Comment: Yes @steve those files Are in a subdir - How you could tell from that little info is amazing!

Comment: @steve @Jesse_b - ls in the dir says the file exists for both `*rammar*` and `*7eNA9*`

Comment: I'd like to suggest this is kept open. It's a unintuitive feature of `ls` that really easily catches beginners out. And there's a really good answer, too.

Comment: @roaima: With all due respect, I disagree.  (1) I understand the answer, because I read all the comments under the question.  I’m concerned that anybody who actually had this problem would have difficulty understanding Kusalananda’s prose.  (2) Getting into this situation requires, IMHO, an extraordinary lack of self- and situational-awareness.  A mere 21 minutes after the question was posted, Jesse_b posted a comment suggesting that the OP run `ls` without arguments to see the contents of current directory.  Doing so would have resolved the question (or at least transmogrified it). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I doubt that any future user who has this problem will be able to find this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shell globbing pattern will expand to *any* name that matches it, regardless of whether the name is that of a regular file or a directory.  When `ls` is given the name of a directory on the command line, it will list its contents.

It seems as if one or several of the names reported by `ls` for `ls *rammar*` may come from a directory whose name matches that pattern.  One of these files is that last file in the `ls` output.

This is why, when you try your second command, the file can not be found. It's not available in the current directory.

---

Summary of main points from comments:

I suggested that

```
find . -type f -name '*7eNA90*`
```

would find the file, and also added that it was important to quote the `*7eNA90*` pattern in this case so that the shell does not try to expand it (it is used by `find`).

@iletras tried this and it worked, but he also found that it worked *without* the quotes.  It works without the quotes since there is nothing matching the pattern in the current directory, so the shell leaves the pattern unexpanded.

However, making it a habit to rely on this behaviour is dangerous, as in the general case, one may not always know or remember what names are, or will be, available in the current directory. Some shells also have shell options for expanding non-matched patterns to the empty string, such as the `nullglob` shell option in `bash`. Setting this shell option would make the command fail if the pattern was unquoted.

It is safer to simply quote the pattern than to rely on circumstances.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for 'splaining "behind the scenes" things. Before your answer, I thought I needed to edit my question to deal with -R vs current dir - now I don't

Comment: Can you say why `ls -R *7eNA9*` from the dir above doesn't work? Did you say it already and I didn't get it?

Comment: @iletras It won't work because the filename globbing pattern is still expanded against the names in the current directory.  This expansion happens before `ls` is even invoked by the shell.

Comment: @iletras You could use `find . -type f -name '*7eNA9*'`. Note that the pattern has to be quoted here, so that the shell doesn't try to expand it.

Comment: @iletras Or, if you know it's a file in a subdirectory, you could use `ls */*7eNA9*`, but that would also have the issue that it may match the names of _directories_ (in the most general case at least, unless you _know_ you don't have directories that matches that pattern).

Comment: Playing with the commands you showed, one's output stumped me. From the parent dir where no `*7eNA9*` exists, `find` found the file with and without quotes around the name fragment  vs "the pattern has to be quoted" ? Thank you in advance @Kusalanand!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77747/discussion-between-iletras-and-kusalananda).

Comment: @iletras See further comments in the above chat.

Comment: “It seems as if one ***or several*** of the names reported by `ls` … may come from a directory …” I believe that all the names must come from a directory. If `ls` is given two or more arguments, and one or more of them is a directory, it will print a separate header line for each directory. Apparently the OP wasn’t getting that.